# cant recive data from WebService via Android ksoap2

Tags: java, android, ksoap2

i'am trying to send string to webservice and get replay from.

i use android studio for programming on java for android

and visual-studio 2010 for programming the C# webservice.

i have this code on android

```
 private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HELO";

    private static final String OPERATION_NAME = "HELO";// your webservice web method name

    private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

    private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://10.0.0.2/WS_TEST/Service1.asmx";



            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, OPERATION_NAME);
            PropertyInfo info= new PropertyInfo();
            info = new PropertyInfo();
            //Set Name
            info.setName("HELO");
            //Set Value
            info.setValue("New User");
            //Set dataType
            info.setType(String.class);
            //Add the property to request object
            request.addProperty(info);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;

            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
            try {
                httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                Object response = envelope.getResponse();
                tvData1.setText(response.toString());
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                tvData1.setText(exception.toString());
            }

and this my C# WebService

     [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
        [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
        [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
        // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
        // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
        public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
        {

            [WebMethod]
            public string HELO(string Name)
            {
                return "Hello : " + Name;
            }

        }
```

and i got only **Helo:**     without the string that i send
instead of   **Helo: New User**

thans

Comment: i have same problem...... Maybe someone can help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
//Set Name
            info.setName("HELO");
```

to this:

```
//Set Name
            info.setName("Name");
```